# Make clone of array (not copy of reference) and modify the new array

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach

I assume my issue is easy to fix but as beeing a newbee I can not get there.

```
const arr1 = [
  { department: "Lebensmittel", id: "id6", product: "Nudeln", status: false },
  { department: "Ceralien", id: "id5", product: "Marmelade", status: false },
  { department: "Ceralien", id: "id3", product: "Müsli", status: false },
  { department: "Ceralien", id: "id4", product: "Honig", status: false },
  { department: "Molkereiprodukte", id: "id1", product: "Milch", status: false }
];

let testArr = [...arr1];

testArr.forEach(obj => (obj.status = "test"));

console.log(arr1, testArr)
```

The log shows, that the forEach() functions gets also applied on the arr1. Why is this and how can I keep arr1 unmutable?

```
arr1 = [
  { department: "Lebensmittel", id: "id6", product: "Nudeln", status: false },
  { department: "Ceralien", id: "id5", product: "Marmelade", status: false },
  { department: "Ceralien", id: "id3", product: "Müsli", status: false },
  { department: "Ceralien", id: "id4", product: "Honig", status: false },
  { department: "Molkereiprodukte", id: "id1", product: "Milch", status: false }
];

 testArr = [
  { department: "Lebensmittel", id: "id6", product: "Nudeln", status: false },
  { department: "Ceralien", id: "id5", product: "Marmelade", status: false },
  { department: "Ceralien", id: "id3", product: "Müsli", status: false },
  { department: "Ceralien", id: "id4", product: "Honig", status: false },
  { department: "Molkereiprodukte", id: "id1", product: "Milch", status: false }
];
```

Comment: https://www.ecosia.org/search?tt=mzl2&q=js+clone+array

Comment: You are confusing the outer array with making copies of the objects inside them also. `[...arr1]` only makes a shallow copy, the objects inside are not copied so references are the same between the two arrays

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`arr1` contains objects, so just cloning `arr1` is not enough. You need to clone the objects in the `arr1` too.

You can use `.map()` function and the spread operator to create a new array that contains clones of the objects in `arr1`.

```js
const arr1 = [
  { department: "Lebensmittel", id: "id6", product: "Nudeln", status: false },
  { department: "Ceralien", id: "id5", product: "Marmelade", status: false },
  { department: "Ceralien", id: "id3", product: "Müsli", status: false },
  { department: "Ceralien", id: "id4", product: "Honig", status: false },
  { department: "Molkereiprodukte", id: "id1", product: "Milch", status: false }
];

let testArr = arr1.map(obj => ({...obj}));

testArr.forEach(obj => (obj.status = "test"));

console.log(arr1[0]);
console.log(testArr[0]);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Using `.map()` function allows you to update the returned objects as well. So you could remove `forEach` loop and just use `.map()` function to not only clone the objects but also update the `status` property of the cloned object.

```js
const arr1 = [
  { department: "Lebensmittel", id: "id6", product: "Nudeln", status: false },
  { department: "Ceralien", id: "id5", product: "Marmelade", status: false },
  { department: "Ceralien", id: "id3", product: "Müsli", status: false },
  { department: "Ceralien", id: "id4", product: "Honig", status: false },
  { department: "Molkereiprodukte", id: "id1", product: "Milch", status: false }
];

let testArr = arr1.map(obj => ({...obj, status: 'test'}));

console.log(arr1[0]);
console.log(testArr[0]);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 2):

In your example the object are byRef. This means that they are not deep copied. You can create a new Array by using map and Object.assign:

```
const testArr = arr1.map(i => Object.assign({}, i));
```

Then after running:

```
testArr.forEach(obj => (obj.status = "test"));
console.log(arr1, testArr)
```

You can see that the arr1 objects where not mutated (screenshot from my console):
[image]

Answer (score 0):

if you want keep your original data without mutate it you could use `map` or `Object.assign`

```js
const arr1 = [ { department: "Lebensmittel", id: "id6", product: "Nudeln", status: false }, { department: "Ceralien", id: "id5", product: "Marmelade", status: false }, { department: "Ceralien", id: "id3", product: "Müsli", status: false }, { department: "Ceralien", id: "id4", product: "Honig", status: false }, { department: "Molkereiprodukte", id: "id1", product: "Milch", status: false } ];
   
const newarray=  arr1.map(o=>({...o,["status"]:"test"}))
 console.log(arr1)
 console.log(newarray)
```

Comment: Your map simply returns the same object reference. That is not a deep copy. You can see it in the `status` properties of your two logs...they are the same in both arrays

Comment: @ charlietfl Thank you for the feedback It's fixed now

Comment: ok... just an FYI now, you don't need both destructuring and Object.assign. You are basically making two new objects  using both

Comment: can you elaborate on that more please

Comment: `{...o,["status"]:"test"}` is a new object ... then when you pass that to Object.assign() it creates another new object from the first new object. Look at the other answers that use one or the other approach and work fine

Comment: yes, what do you recommend or suggest to prevent that use only one of them?

Comment: @charlietfl Thank you very much for such a valuable feedback

Comment: I have changed that, can you check it out and let me know if there is anything else has to be fixed?

Comment: Well actually there is  small issue ...`newarray` is being declared as global with no `const, let or var`

Comment: Yeah true it's one of them bad habits when writing a code in `js`  that is fixed, hopefully it's the last issue in this tiny code lol

Answer (score -2):

in javascript, `clonedArray=originalArray` just creates a reference == the same array.
you can overcome this/"clone" a simple array by:

```
clonedArray=originalArray.slice()
```

or, for complex (say, with objects), the "quickest" way is:

```
clonedArray=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(originalArray))
```

Comment: The arrays contain objects, and `.slice()` will not clone those.

Comment: And the `[... arr1]` code in the OP basically does the same thing

Comment: @Pointy, thank you.  When I need a "quick fix" I just use JSON.  OP said `[...arr1]` didn't work..

Comment: Another down-voter...  Well, it's a correct answer.  Just up-vote what you think is better.  That's kindness.

Comment: the problem is that your first solution will have *exactly the same problem* that the OP is asking here, and for exactly the same reason. Cloning with the JSON API can work in many cases, but there are object graphs that cannot be serialized successfully (consider object properties with Date or function values).

Answer (score -2):

Another suggestion is third party package lodash to do a deepcopy (removes references) -                    https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#cloneDeep

Comment: It's a matter of preference - I try to use pure javascript.

Comment: Link only answers are not very valuable and are frowned on. The link should only be used to support what actually exists in the question itself. Providing lodash code that makes the deep copy while maintaining link to the docs would be the proper way to use this solution in your answer